# Using FileWriter write data in a cell

Tags: android, csv, multiline, filewriter

I want to write comma separated data in CSV file. Writing http request response in it.

Following is the code-

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Constants.LOGGING_FILE_PATH, true);
fw.write(currTime + ","+ responseBody);
fw.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

Now problem is response is multiline, So when data is shown in Excel it messed up. I have attached screen shot. Can I have all data in one cell. Like ALT+ENTER.[image]

Comment: Try this code :

CSVWriter writer = null;
try 
{
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/myfile.csv"), ',');
    String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#"); // array of your values
    writer.writeNext(entries);  
    writer.close();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    //error
}

Comment: Watch this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632501/android-generate-csv-file-from-table-values

Comment: You can get list of data in one string and set it in the cell. Like : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/

Comment: mayurvpatel110, not working. Its saving data with hash.

Comment: And I want to use FIleWriter without using CSV lib.